# Cant use gmail smtp to send email via c# form app

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I wrote this code in c# .net form app to send emails. Code is working with yahoo,hotmail,gmx by replacing the smtp servers name but not working with gmail,

```
            try
            {

                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(youremail.Text);
                mail.To.Add(txtreceiver.Text);
                mail.Subject = txtsubject.Text;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = txtbody.Text;
                SmtpServer.Port = 465;
                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(youremail.Text, yourpass.Text);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Sent sucessfully..!  \n If Email is not found in inbox check junk ");
            }
            catch (Exception s)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failled To Send Mail..!");
            }
```

Comment: gmail SMTP port is 587. Also, provide exact error message/exception which is thrown.

Comment: i have also tried 587 not working

Comment: provide exact error message/exception which is thrown. on gmail account, has "allow less secure applications" been enabled?

Comment: here is debug log "A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll"

Comment: that isn't useful. Need the full exception message, including stacktrace.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: have you enabled "less secure applications" on the gmail account?

Comment: user1666620 bro "My Account" -> "Sign-in & Security" -> "Connected Apps & Sites". At the bottom of that page, toggle the "Allow less secure apps" option. this was the prob how can i rate your answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you must use port 587 as @user1666620 suggested in the comments.

Then you will also need to allow "less secure" devices to access that GMail account. Click on your account avatar, then "My Account" -> "Sign-in & Security" -> "Connected Apps & Sites". At the bottom of that page, toggle the "Allow less secure apps" option.

Comment: "My Account" -> "Sign-in & Security" -> "Connected Apps & Sites". At the bottom of that page, toggle the "Allow less secure apps" option. worked :)

Comment: Glad that helped! Struggled with the same problem a couple of weeks ago.